# Google script hangs when called from sheet via custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a script (named "archiveCopy") that works great - copies a workbook, renames the copy, then puts the copy into a specified folder.

Now, I want to create a menu to run the script from the sheet, but the onOpen script isn't working (or at least I don't think it's working).

Here's my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Archive')
    .addItem('archiveCopy','archiveCopy')
    .addToUi();
}

function archiveCopy() {
  var myValue =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("O49").getValue();
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1errc7-2sMGB1Vc_sxNwZPKJIxjZOTRWo");
  DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(myValue,destinationFolder);
}
```

The script "archiveCopy" works great if I run it from the sheet's Script Editor. When I try to run the script from the custom menu, however, everything hangs.

The error that I get isn't really an error - it's the normal "Running Script" yellow box. It just won't go away!

Why? And how to fix!

Comment: Please try to format your code in the future. I have created a test spreadsheet and it worked fine in both scenarios, running from the menu, however, did take 3.2 seconds as opposed to 2.7 from the script editor.

Comment: Apologies, Vytautas. I simply cic a copy/paste to my code in the script editor window. If I did something that offended you, please enlighten me so that I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: Anyhow, all fixed, as the custom menu worked properly on my machine. I will try this again on a different machine later today to see if it will make any difference. (I don't think so.)

Comment: Not sure how that would offend anyone, just makes it easier to understand the code at a glance rather than having to copy everything out to read properly. A different machine should not make any difference, as Google Apps Scripts run on Google servers. Might be dependant on how large the file is and what the contents are.